# How to treat nodes with xlmns?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquivoposicao_4_01 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
                     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<fundo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

I would like to get the informations of the node `<fundo>`, but i have some xmls that came like the above: `<fundo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">`

How can i do a `<xsl:for-each select="fundo">` when exists a namespace like that?

Comment: You do not *ignore* the namespace; you *use* it. -- P.S. Please post a **complete** example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the namespace with a *prefix* and use it to qualify the XPath selectors for the elements which are part of that namespace. You can do that by adding an `xmlns` declaration to your `xsl:stylesheet`, with any prefix:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/"> <!-- add this declaration -->
```

Now you select `fundo` qualifying the selector with the prefix you declared. In this example you would do that using `ns1:fundo`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns1:fundo">
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**Option 1**

Declare the namespace (add `xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/"` to `xsl:stylesheet`) and use that in your xpath (the "t" prefix can be anything):

```
<xsl:for-each select="t:fundo"></xsl:for-each>
```

**Option 2**

Use `local-name()` in the xpath:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='fundo']"></xsl:for-each>
```

You can also use `namespace-uri()` to make sure you're selecting exactly what you want:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[local-name()='fundo' and namespace-uri()='http://tempuri.org/']"></xsl:for-each>
```

**Option 3** (XSLT 2.0 only)

Use `*` for the prefix:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*:fundo"></xsl:for-each>
```

This can be combined with `namespace-uri()` in option 2.

**Option 4** (XSLT 2.0 only)

Add the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute to `xsl:stylesheet`:

```
 xpath-default-namespace="http://tempuri.org/"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an XML like:

```
<fundo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

or

```
<t:fundo xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/">
```

The name of the element `fundo` can be read like `{http://tempuri.org/}:fundo`. The element is in the specific namespace. So ignoring it is not a good idea, it would change the semantics.

Xpath uses aliases for the namespaces, too. So you have to define the namespaces on the XSL Stylesheet element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:temp="http://tempuri.org/">
```

The definition is separate and independent from the definition in the source XML. You are now able to access the element `fundo` in the namespace `http://tempuri.org/` using the alias/prefix `temp`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="temp:fundo">
```